# Stationary test using augmented dickey- fuller test

Tags: r

Am trying to do this but the  test statistics does not include in my result

```
Adf.test(agric, alternative = c( "stationary","explosive"), k=trunc( (length (agric)-1)^(1/8)))
```

The out put only show p value dickey fuller value 
Pls I need someone should put me through on r how I can get the test statistic on this

Answer (score 1):

Is this from the `tseries` package? The full tutorial can be run like this.

```
library(tseries)
x <- rnorm(1000)
adf.test(x, alternative = c("stationary", "explosive"),
         k = trunc((length(x)-1)^(1/3)))
```

You should supply the vector object `x` to the function `adf.test()`.

**Edit**: Try

```
library(urca)
ur.df(x)
```

Comment: Yes have done that but the test statistics value is not in my result my x is my agric